# cannot get readline working in perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging, readline

I'm in cygwin, but I tried Ubuntu and Fedora - regardless whether I install Term::ReadKey and Term::ReadLine::Gnu and Term::ReadLine::Perl local (cygwin) or as sudo (Ubuntu, Fedora), I just can't get previous commands with the Up Arrow key. Please help :)

```
$ cpan Term::ReadKey
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.53)
Reading '/home/user/.local/share/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 20 Sep 2015 01:17:02 GMT
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20150520)
Term::ReadKey is up to date (2.33).

user@user-PC /cygdrive/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp
$ cpan Term::ReadLine::Gnu
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.53)
Reading '/home/user/.local/share/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 20 Sep 2015 01:17:02 GMT
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20150520)
Term::ReadLine::Gnu is up to date (1.27).

user@user-PC /cygdrive/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp
$ cpan Term::ReadLine::Perl
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.53)
Reading '/home/user/.local/share/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 20 Sep 2015 01:17:02 GMT
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20150520)
Term::ReadLine::Perl is up to date (1.0303).
```

Comment: What do you get instead?

Comment: Nothing - no action at all..

Comment: Did you try restarting your bash session?  If that does not work, check the bash man page for `readline`

Comment: Okay, it's not that bad :) I get history for commands like 'p $var_name' but not for just 'p' and 'l' - which were what I was using the test whether I had command-line history or not... So I can say all is well..